# JQuery плавный переход

Tags: jquery

Проблема с плавным переходом картинки, картинка просто меняется и всё, но не плавно.

Вот пример моей попытки:

```
$("#klubnika").hover(function() {
  $("#klubnika").attr("src","img/team-section/banka-klub.jpg");
    },function() {
          $("#klubnika").attr("src","img/team-section/klubnika.jpg");
    }
);
```

Comment: Как я понял, вы хотите по наведению мыши сменить картинку, возможно проще это будет сделать средствами css, или для этой задачи вам обязательно использовать jQuery?

Comment: Jquery)) Просто на нём учусь

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант использовать вместо смены атрибута, использовать два изображения и метод [fadeOut()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%B8c%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8).

```js
$('#front-side').hover(function() {
  $('#front-side').fadeOut(1000, "linear");
});

$('#back-side').mouseout(function() {
  $('#front-side').fadeIn(1000, "linear");
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img id="back-side" src="http://mirpozitiva.ru/uploads/posts/2016-09/1474011210_15.jpg" />
  <img id="front-side" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQo4D5EOmasw-Rkq7QXD3V4fW3r5qDxRm9Ke1Rhmjxi3NC6yDiElA" />
</div>
```

Comment: что то ваш пример не работает...в  ubuntu firefox

Comment: Честно, не могу проверить в ubuntu firefox, под windows все работает, если у вас есть какое-то решение этой проблемы, то можете дать рекомендации по их устранению, или опубликовать свой ответ на данный вопрос лишенный данного недостатка.

Comment: прошу прощения - работает - только в одну сторону , потому и не заметил - извените

Comment: @МаксимЛенский ничего страшного, заодно решил добавить переход в обратную сторону, так даже лучше, так что спасибо.

Comment: + от меня ... это возращает первую картинку `mouseout` ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский да, когда мышь покидает вторую картинку, то у первой срабатывает `fadeIn`.

Comment: хм.... спс за объяснение